# How a function with O(n^2) is faster than O(n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have two different JS functions `foo` and `bar` and both are doing the same thing but in a different way.

`foo` has the complexity of `O(n)` whereas `bar` has the complexity of `O(n*n)` but when I run both the functions with the same dataset, `bar` performs better most of the time even with more time complexity.

What are the factors which are making a function with `O(n*n)` perform faster than `O(n)` and why `O(n)` is slower?

```
const LANGUAGES = {
  ENGLISH_US: 'en-US',
  ENGLISH_UK: 'en-GB'
}

const COMPANIES = [
    'Apple',
  'Samsung',
  'Huawei',
  'One Plus',
  'Google',
  'Sony',
  'Vivo',
  'LG'
];

const loading = false;
const showLG = false;

const generateData = () => {
    const res = [];
  let counter = 0;
  for(let i=1; i<250; ++i) {
    if (counter <= 6) {
        res.push({id: i, type: COMPANIES[counter]});
      ++counter;
    }
    else {
        counter = 0;
      res.push({id: i, type: COMPANIES[counter]});
      ++counter;
    }
  }
  res.push({id: 25, type: 'LG'});
  return res;
}

const data = {
  elements : {
      language: 'en-US',
      phones: generateData(),
    }
}

function foo() {
  const typesCount = data?.elements?.phones?.reduce((acc, { type }) => {
    if (acc[type] === undefined) {
      acc[type] = 0
    }
    return { ...acc, [type]: acc[type] + 1 };
  }, {});

  const isLGPresent = !!typesCount['LG'];

  COMPANIES.forEach(type => {
    delete typesCount[type];
  })

  const unsupportedTypes = !!Object.values(typesCount).length;

  const lgCheck = !showLG && !isLGPresent;

  const isLangSupported = Object.values(LANGUAGES).includes(data?.elements?.language);

  const isSupported = !unsupportedTypes && lgCheck && isLangSupported;

  if (!loading && !isSupported) {
    // console.log('foo')
  }
}

function bar() {
  const isPhoneSupported = data?.elements?.phones?.every(
    ({ type }) => COMPANIES.includes(type),
  );

  const lgCheck = !showLG
    && data?.elements?.phones?.every(({ type }) => type !== 'LG');

  const isLangSupported = Object.values(LANGUAGES).includes(
    data?.elements?.language,
  );

  const isSupported = isPhoneSupported
    && lgCheck
    && isLangSupported;

  if (!loading && !isSupported) {
    // console.log('bar')
  }
};

// for warm up
let start = performance.now();
foo();
let end = performance.now();


let start1 = performance.now();
foo();
let end1 = performance.now();
let timeTaken1 = end1 - start1;


let start2 = performance.now();
bar();
let end2 = performance.now();
let timeTaken2 = end2 - start2;


console.log(`Time taken 1: ${timeTaken1}`);
console.log(`Time taken 2: ${timeTaken2}`);
console.log(`Difference: ${timeTaken2 - timeTaken1}`);
```

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, `.includes()` is *extremely* fast in modern JavaScript runtimes.

Comment: Oh also, `foo()` is also O(n*n) because of the spread syntax used in the `typesCount` callback. This would be better: `acc[type] = acc[type] + 1; return acc;`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pointy. Can you please also refer some links where I can find `.includes()` is faster and spread syntax complexity?

Comment: Well like I said, `.includes()` confuses me a lot. It probably has to do with some internal optimization done by V8 or whatever runtime. The handling of object properties in modern JavaScript is insanely intricate and optimized. Probably if you have an array with 20,000 elements in it, `.includes()` would behave like you would expect, an `O(n)` search.

Comment: [Temporary hastebin](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/xododapano.typescript) for the above code to improve  readability, Do not feel comfortable editing to it because it is not pure formatting(removed a stray comma, normalized statements to have semicolons, and changed text from "test1", "test2" to "foo" and "bar".

Comment: Do not confuse algorithmic complexity with speed. It just means you need to test on a larger dataset.

Comment: @Bergi even with a large dataset `bar` performs better

Comment: Complexity just shows how the function grows and not how fast it is.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, I understood the point now. Thanks :) But which one should matter more: A function with less complexity but slow or A function with more complexity but fast?

Comment: @newbie The one that performs better for your use cases, of course! And if you're really serious, you put a function in front to check which should be faster and use the faster approach for whatever data you're given.

Comment: "even with a large dataset `bar` performs better".  Then you need a still-larger dataset.  Algorithmic complexity is important, but because the coefficients can be arbitrary, all you can tell for certain is that something that is `O(n^2)` will take more time than something that is `O(n)`, *when `n` is large enough*.  That threshold might be a trillion or a googol-plex.  So keep algorithmic complexity in mind, but don't let it drive too many of your decisions.  Fast enough is measured by your requirements and your expected data size.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet but I guess in this case as pointed out by Pointy that due to `spread` syntax is making the `foo` complexity `O(n*n)` so both `foo` and `bar` are kinda same here.

Comment: @newbie: That's a quick fix, though, and if the issue still stands, just remember that big-O notation is important to understand, but for many cases not a critical factor.